# La tipografía de mi web se hace pequeña de pronto

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, responsive

Escribo este post para preguntar sobre un asunto que me está volviendo loco. He diseñado una página web para un cliente, y por algún motivo que desconozco, el tamaño de la tipografía disminuye mucho cuando visualizo la web en mi portátil (Macbook Air de 13") tanto en Chrome, como Firefox y Safari. La web está realizada en Wordpress con un template.

La cuestión es que en mi ordenador de sobremesa (Windows 24") y en mi móvil (Android) el tamaño de la tipografía se muestra correctamente, pero al pasarme al portátil, aparece muy pequeño todo, y no encuentro la manera de cambiarlo. **No es una cuestión de zoom**, estoy visualizando la web al 100% de zoom.

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. La web en cuestión es:

https://oceanqigong.com/es/

Muchas gracias a todos! Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué has probado? ¿Qué código tienes? No vamos a mirar el código de una web entera

Comment: Cada navegador se comporta distinto relacionado con los Estilos de css y fuentes no tiene nada que ver con el sistema operativo *windos o android* que uses es mas bien los navegadores.
Mi solución seria ver el CSS de esos textos en específico en cada navegador para poder ver en cuál navegador específico no está agarrando el tamaño de la tipografía y poder agregar una nueva clase CSS para ese tipo de navegador. Deberías saber diseño web básico en preferencia CSS *estilo en cascada* para poder cambiar eso en WordPress seguro existen plugin para validar en cada navegador, pero si sabes CSS solo c

Comment: Listo, es el tamaño de letra que estás usando. CSS puede ser la razón. La resolución de tu portátil debe ser mayor seguro. El macbook air retina, tiene una resolución nativa de 2560 XDDD Ahora, que nos dice esto...

Comment: Si una pantalla de 1mt x 1mt tengo 100 pixeles x 100 pixeles, y mi letra es de 50 pixeles, la letra me usará la mitad de la pantalla. Pero si en esa misma pantalla, los pixeles son 1000px x 1000px... crees que mantendrá la relación de aspecto ?? para nada, la letra se hará pequeña de inmediato.

Comment: En resumen, tu problema es la unidad del tamaño de letra, la cual probablemente este en pixeles, cuando debiese estar en .rem, u otra unidad de mejor relacion de aspecto.

Comment: -> El error simulado -> https://i.gyazo.com/d973351c35a203d7ff52807211ab961f.mp4